# Jquery disable form button until click on a non form element

Tags: php, jquery, forms, click, submit

i have a simple list, that is not included in a form, and a form.

What i want to do: i want that the submit button of the form to be enabled only when someone clicks on one element of that list. 
Is this possible using jquery?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this
HTML

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<form>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list > li').click(function() {
        $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/r6nUD/

Answer (score 1):

Set the button to disabled initially (e.g. by adding `disabled="disabled"` directly in the HTML) and define appropriate action for click event of your list:

```
$("#the_list").bind("click", function() {
    $("#submit_button").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: cool, but it does't remove the disabled on element click yet... though i have added the script and the appropriate styles.

Comment: Apparently the `click' rather than `change` event is appropriate in this case. (I've edited the answer to reflect that).

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#MyList').click(function() {
          $('#submitButton').removeAttr("disabled");
       });
    });
</script>

    <ul id="MyList">
     <li>element1</li>
     <li>element2</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" disabled="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here I used sample HTML.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
   $('#myform input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
});
```